# Condition for if the page is one sided

Tags: double-sided, ifthenelse, single-sided

I want to do something like below

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\begin{documnet}
\if@twoside
The page is doublesided. All good.
\else
\textbf{{\Huge The page is not double sided! change!}}
\fi

\end{document}
```

To make sure that I haven't forget to make onesided mode to double sided mode before printing out a book.

I'm using oneside when I'm writing just because the computer screen is single sided.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: as you have it but you need `\makeatletter` to use `\if@twoside`

Comment: note `\Huge`  does not take an argument, so `\Huge The page..` not `\Huge{The page...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 
Is there any other way? Should I always include `\makeatletter`?

Comment: How do I protect other parts of the text to be `\Huge` then?
`{ \Huge blah }` ?

Comment: you need to makeatletter or place the command in a package to use commands with @ in their name. you could use `\csname if@twoside\endcsname`  if you wanted to avoid `\makeatletter` but that makes nesting harder.

Comment: for huge yes try `\Huge{One} two`  you will see `two ` is huge as well.

Comment: Ah I see, I will stick with makeatletter then. thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the computer screen is single sided"? I produce a PDF file and the display (evince) by default shows each individual page, not pairwise pages. The pages are displayed as they would be if printed --- different margins on odd and even pages. Try just using the `twoside` option and forget about using your `\if@twoside` code.

Comment: We don't flip through a computer screen

Comment: @Tom Does that mean that all your pages are assembled into a single graphic?

Comment: No, the left and right margines in onesided mode and twosided mode are different. If I'm reading a PDF document on a computer screen by scrolling, these things are annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change from

```
\if@twoside
The page is doublesided. All good.
\else
\textbf{{\Huge The page is not double sided! change!}}
\fi
```

to

```
\makeatletter
\if@twoside
The page is doublesided. All good.
\else
\textbf{{\Huge The page is not double sided! change!}}
\fi
\makeatother
```

by embracing the condition with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.
So that latex reads the variable `@twoside` correctly (`\makeatother` reverts the compiler to read `@` symbols in a default way (I think).